# IN mysql with fractional values

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT * FROM salers WHERE comm IN (0.12, 0,13, 0.15);
```

query returns an empty set while any other queries returns values. Where do I make mistake here?

Comment: what is the datatype of `comm` column ?

Comment: Typo? Do you want a comma between 0 and 13?

Comment: Post 'comm' column values and datatype

Comment: comm datatype is float,  values are: 0.12  , 0.13 , 0.10 , 0.11 ,  0.15.  The comma between 0.13 is a mistake, but even with  a dot it returns empty set

Comment: General tip: never do equals comparisons on float values. (incl. IN.)

Answer (score 2):

"Fractional" values are represented either as fixed-point values (`decimal`) or as floating point values.  The latter are very troublesome when used with equality operations.

So, in addition to the mistake with the comma, this can be dangerous if `comm` is `double` or `float`.  You may find that this works better:

```
where cast(comm as decimal(10, 2)) in (0.12, 0.13, 0.15)
```

Or, preferably, you can look for a range:

```
where comm > 0.11 and comm < 0.16
```

Comment: Changed value to decimal and IN worked. Thanks everybody. The values answers were really valuable.

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is at : **0,13**

Change to:

```
SELECT * FROM salers WHERE comm IN (0.12, 0.13, 0.15);
```